# xterm set geometry and then execute script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, xterm

what I want do to is:

xterm -geometry 93x31+100+350 -e ./script.sh

However, I can't set the geometry and launch a script, only either launch a script or set the geometry of a new window. Is there a terminal application which can do this?

Comment: `xterm` supports doing both at the same time; what happens when you try that?

Comment: `xterm -geometry 93x31+100+350 -e "./256-colors.sh ; sleep 5"` works here, but without that `sleep`, the window does not stay around log enough to see.

Comment: It works for me even with much more complicated xterm command lines. Which Linux distro and and version are you running?

Answer (score 3):

The [**`-e`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#OPTIONS:-e) option tells xterm to run just that command.  If you give no **`-e`** option, xterm starts a shell.  Either way, xterm creates a window showing the output from the command or shell.

Shells prompt for input and do not exit until there is no more input.

If the command specified with **`-e`** exits quickly (e.g., does not prompt for input), the window created with **`-e`** will go away quickly.

You can keep the window created for [**`-e`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#OPTIONS:-e) by various methods:

- make the command prompt for input (wait for the user to respond)
- make the command run a long time
- use the [**`-hold`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#OPTIONS:-hold) option (which keeps the window after the command has exited).

(The **`-geometry`** option is independent of the **`-e`** option).